# Google chrome taking too much time to open

Tags: google-chrome

For quite a few days, Google chrome is taking a long time to open in my OS.I use Ubuntu 18.04. Can anybody suggest a solution to this?

Comment: How long is "a long time?"

Comment: Make a new user, then logout and login as the new user. Does Chrome take as long for the new user? If not, then it's a corrupted user profile.